# Native Android select menu - Cordova Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, select, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I just wondering if is there any cordova plugin can convert select tag to a native android context menu or at least enhance performance and behaviour of the select tag ?

Note : I am using ionic cordova framework

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

could you check that plugin at cordova-plugin-context-menu

it's found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-context-menu

it's very simple to use where you can just initialize an array of objects and add entries to it - those entries would represent your menu items. see an example below:

```
var entries = [];
entries.push({
    title: 'Entry 1',
    id: 'test'
});

entries.push({
    title: 'Entry 2',
    id: 'foo'
});

entries.push({
    title: '',
    id: '',
    isSeparator: true
});

entries.push({
    title: 'Entry 3',
    id: 'bar'
});



var context = {
    title: 'Title',
    items: entries,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}
ContextMenu.open(context, function (ele) {
    console.log('You clicked the entry with an id of ' + ele);
}););
```

You can then use this plugin to show a native context menu that will make the user select between either the device storage or external ones. For example

Upload from:

1. Device Storage.
2. Dropbox.

Hope this helps